# Timeout for System.Timers.Timer and exception throwing

Tags: c#, .net-core, timer, system.timers.timer

I'm using a .NET System Timer to do some actions in a regular interval.

Is there a way to make the timer stop working after a defined time somehow in its definition? Or do I have to use a second timer which will stop the first?

Also, when the timeout hits, I want to throw an exception. It's my understanding that `System.Timers.Timer` silently swallows the exception. How can I throw the exception to the invoking thread which created the timer?

Comment: how about using some cron jobs library?

Comment: Sounds like you need something more sophisticated than timers. Maybe Quartz.NET or Hangfire or something alike?

Comment: @Fildor have no idea what it is.. I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on keeping a timer to do this, you could compute a dead-line when starting the timer and check that deadline in each tick:

```
// inside Tick-handler method
if( DateTime.Now > _deadline ) throw new TimerShouldDieException();
```

However if you want to inform some other entity that this happened, throwing an Exception won't be enough. In that case, you maybe want to fire an event:

```
// inside Tick-handler method
if( DateTime.Now > _deadline )
{
     OnTimerExpired(_timer);
     throw new TimerShouldDieException();
}
```

And lastly, instead of rudely throwing an exception, it may be preferable to just stop the timer:

```
// inside Tick-handler method
if( DateTime.Now > _deadline )
{
     _timer.Stop(); // Assuming you have a class field for this timer named "_timer";
     OnTimerExpired(_timer);
}
```

Comment: If an exception is thrown by a callback which is passed to the timer (like you OnTimerExpired example which I assumes is something from outside) then will the exception be swallowed or can it be caught by the calling thread?

Comment: Well the calling thread would be the timer thread. But I'd suggest against throwing anyway. There are cleaner ways to stop a timer.

Comment: Let's assume I need to throw an exception anyway.. how would I catch it in the invoking thread?

Comment: As far as I can remember, it _will_ be swallowed, i.e. not be visible from outside the timer. That's why I proposed firing an event. Another, much more imprecise method would be to use a Watchdog to detect if the timer fired or not ... or setting some sort of switch which then must be monitored, too. So baseline for me would be that some sort of Event or Callback would be the way to go.

Comment: ^^ Or useage of a more sophisticated Scheduling Framework that supports number of triggers or deadline or a mix thereof ... whatever you need.